# Treat character as literal in strptime

Tags: python, datetime

Another application that I have no control over returns datetime values as `Jan 1, 2019 09:00:00.000 X-0500`. The `X` preceeding the timezone is driving me bonker since I cannot find out how to ignore it. Without the `X`, this works:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('Jan 1, 2019 09:00:00.000 -0500', '%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S.%f %z')
```

I can manually remove the `X` but is there a way to write the format string such that Python treats the `X` as a literal `X` with no special meaning?

```
datetime.strptime('Jan 1, 2019 09:00:00.000 X-0500', '???')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write a literal `X` in the format string:

```
datetime.strptime('Jan 1, 2019 09:00:00.000 X-0500', '%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S.%f X%z')
                                                                            ^
```

Comment: So simple and yet so elusive. Thank you!